# Add network latency to Spark Docker cluster

Tags: docker, apache-spark, ping

I've setup a Spark Docker standalone cluster with bitnami/spark. I'm running the cluster locally and want to add latency between the containers to simulate a network environment.

Is there any way to do this? I've seen guides using Traffic Control but how do I add it to my bitnami cluster?